# Variable changes with no apparent reason while using class

Tags: php, class, variables, object, get

I am using phpmydatagrid to display many tables.
To determine which table, I am using GET.
This is the class: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/18544.html
The javascript part: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/18559.html 
This is a part of my code:

```
include ("phpmydatagrid.class.php");
$objGrid = new datagrid;
$getId = $_GET['id'];
$tablename = "xxx_$getId";
//Some code here...
$objGrid -> tabla($tablename); //This is how you set the table using the class
```

The table is shown correctly, and if I echo $objGrid->tablename I get the correct table name.
But when you try adding a new row using the interface the table name suddenly becomes "xxx_" without the id.
I looked in the class codes and there's nowhere where 'tablename' is being changed. To the query just search "INSERT INTO" in the class.
I hope I made myself clear enough, also the class file might help you understand.

Comment: you might want to store this in session.

Comment: What code do you use to add a row? Are you still using the same instance? Or has the page been reloaded? I'm asking incase the post variable has expired and it creates a new table instead

Comment: @Floris I did mean tabla because that's how the authour of the class set it to be.

Comment: @LiamSorsby I am using a button, because that is the reason I am using this class. Like I said, you can find the code for adding the row by going in to the class file and searching "INSERT INTO"\

Comment: @LiamSorsby When pressing the button the page does reload. But I don't think that's the problem because after the reload it gives the error but underneath the error my ECHO is still there and the variable is correct. I just noticed that.

Comment: Can you supply the link the button goes too? Just to make sure? Does it still have the get variable?

Comment: @LiamSorsby The URL stays the same, with the get variable. The button starts a javascript function called DG_addrow.
EDIT: my mistake. It's actually starting a function called DG_doSave and passes the data to be saved as an array

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/18559.html
The javascript file